# Camera projection matrix: why transpose rotation matrix?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, rotational-matrices, projection-matrix

In the following:

http://cvlab.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/cvlab2/files/data/strechamvs/rathaus.tar.gz

there's a README file that says:

```
a 3D point X will be projected into the images in the usual way:
x = K[R^T|-R^T t]X
```

I remember that 3D to 2D Camera Projection Matrix requires the R rotation, not the transpose R matrix, i.e. I expect:

```
 x = K[R|-R t]X
```

Why does it say R^T and not simply R ?

Comment: `x = K[R^T|-R^T t]X` is the inverse of `x = K[R|t]X`. I'm not going to download a 90MB tarball just to see what they're actually doing, though.

Comment: x = K[R^T|-R^T t]X is most definitely not the inverse of x = K[R|t]X. Acctually x = K[R^T|-R^T t]X can not be inverted.

Comment: Hey I am having some rectification problems with this same database. From what I understand from the answer, instead of the usual Rotation from World to Camera they have given a Camera to World Rotation matrix. Is this correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends in which direction `R` was determined. I.e. is it a transformation of the camera in the global reference frame, or is it a transformation of the points in the local camera's reference frame.

The true answer is: Don't worry just check that what you've got is right.

Answer (score 2):

Since R^T == R^{-1}, it seems like the upper formula just expects the rotation to be available in the reverse direction of the below one. Just make sure to use the direction they expect as input.